# Using Generalization properly

Tags: java, oop

Suppose you have the following Interfaces

```
public interface Action {
    public State execute(State state);  
}
public interface State {
    public Collection<Action> getPossibleActions(); 
}
```

And this method

```
public static Collection<State> getAllSuccessorStates(State state){
    Collection<State> allSuccessors = new HashSet<>();
    for (Action action: state.getPossibleActions()){
        State successorState = action.execute(state);
        allSuccessors.add(successorState);
        allSuccessors.addAll(getAllSuccessorStates(successorState));
    }
    return allSuccessors;
}
```

A Concrete State could be for example a Chessboard and an Action the movement of a Piece on the board. Obviously the Chess-Actions need to know the concrete State class:

```
public class ChessAction implements Action {
    @Override
    public ChessState execute(ChessState state) {...}
}
```

Which is ofcourse not an allowed way of overriding execute. What would be the correct way of implementing this, so you can have concrete Actions, that operate on concrete States, which you can give as Arguments to getAllSuccessorStates?

I thought about Generics and also got answers pointing to Generics, but that brings about new Problems. If i write the Action class like this:

```
public interface Action<E extends State> {
    public E execute(E state);
}
```

i will have the following Problem with ChessState class:

```
@Override
public Collection<Action<State>> getPossibleActions() {
    Collection<Action<State>> actions = new ArrayList<>();
    actions.add(new ChessAction());
    return actions;
}
```

the line Actions.add causes the following error: *The method add(Action) in the type Collection> is not applicable for the arguments (ChessAction)*

Now i could declare Actions as

```
Collection<Action<ChessState>> actions = new ArrayList<>();
```

but that wont be a permitted return type.

Comment: If ChessState implements State, you need just to change the ChessAction's method as follows : public State execute(State state) {...}, then the polymorphism is enabled, (Note that you can put a ChessState instance in a State variable )

Comment: Technically, implementing interfaces is *Realization* not *Generalization*. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a satisfactory Solution now, which works correctly, doesnt need instanceof and yields no compile warnings:

```
public interface Action<E extends State<?>> {
    public E execute(E state);  
}
public interface State<E extends Action<?>> {
    public Collection<E> getPossibleActions();
}
public static <A extends Action<S>, S extends State<A>> Collection<S> getAllSuccessorStates(S state){
    Collection<S> allSuccessors = new HashSet<>();
    for (A localAction: state.getPossibleActions()){
        S successorState = localAction.execute(state);
        allSuccessors.add(successorState);
        allSuccessors.addAll(getAllSuccessorStates(successorState));
    }
    return allSuccessors;
}
```

Example of using getAllSuccessorStates (i forgo the implementation Details of the concrete classes here, but the Point should be apparent. You can use the method getAllSuccessorStates with any concrete State class, get Instances of this class in return collection and use them)

```
public class TestState implements State<TestAction> {...}
public class TestAction implements Action<TestState> {...}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestState initialState = new TestState("1");
    Collection<TestState> allSuccessorStates = getAllSuccessorStates(initialState);
    for (TestState state: allSuccessorStates){
        System.out.println(state.getStateStr());
    }
}
```

This Question arose from the book "AI-A modern approache" by Stuart Russel and Peter Norvig, in case somebody who reads this book has the same Problem and searches for solutions. In the book the Action and State methods are inside a Problem Class, but i think in this way the OO-design is better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use generics (needs java 1.5 or above):

```
public interface Action<T extends State> {
    public T execute(T state);  
}

public class ChessAction implements Action<ChessState> {
    @Override
    public ChessState execute(ChessState state) {...}
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `ChessState` must have the same signature of `execute` as in the `Action` interface. If you require that `ChessAction.execute` accept only `ChessState`, you can write :

```
public class ChessAction implements Action {
    @Override
    public State execute(State state) 
    {
        if (!(state instanceof ChessState))
            throw new SomeException ();
        ChessState cs = (ChessState) state;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If a `ChessAction` always takes a `ChessState` then generics would be a better approach.

Comment: i'm not a very experienced programmer, but using instanceof isn't really good programming practice, is it?

Comment: @user3144065 It is bad if you use `instanceof Sub-Class` in the code of the super-class, since a super-class is not supposed to know its sub-classes. However, if you have a class that already depends on another class (as `ChessAction` depends on `ChessState`) , I see no problem with having `instanceof ChessState` inside `ChessAction` code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the same inherited method, and it will work since State is a super class for CheesState.

```
public class ChessAction implements Action {
@Override
public State execute(State state) {...}
}
```

Inside the execute method, you can use polymorph method (define in State and redefined ChessState), or you can cast to ChessState (ChessState s = (ChessState) state;), then use it as you need